# Linking to documentation page without function in R using roxygen2

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2, roxygen

I am wondering if there is a possibility, during writing a package in R, to link to the documentation page in R that has no functions included but has only package-info?
For example `\link[stats]{stats-package.R}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possibillities is `\link[stats]{stats-package}`  without `.R` extansion (but it will link to `stats-package` page). If you just want to link the package use `\pkg{package}` e.g. `\pkg{stats}`. For more info try [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-R-documentation-files)

Comment: Ok thanks. \link[stats]{stats-package} works! But \pkg{package} only makes text bold.